# Unable to run "install npm" on GitLab pipeline

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, gitlab

I have a repository generated via `Gatsby`, still in plain vanilla (i.e., I have not edited any of the files generated with `gatsby build`).

I want to push the generated content to my GitLab private project.

I have written the following `.gitlab-ci.yml`, so that the pipeline gets executed after my `push`:

```
build website:
  image: node:16
  script:
    - npm install --loglevel verbose
    - npm install -g gatsby-cli
    - gatsby build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./public
```

On GitLab, the job gets executed, but it fails as the execution exceeds 1 hour.

I notice that certain tasks take quite a long of time, as per the console output.
This is the first one to appear in my console output taking a considerable amount of time:

`npm timing idealTree:init Completed in 813ms`

Also, I get very similar warning messages, showing some dependency-resolution issues, with very high completion times.
For instance:

```
...
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: eslint-config-react-app@6.0.0
npm WARN Found: babel-eslint@undefined
npm WARN node_modules/babel-eslint
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer babel-eslint@"^10.0.0" from eslint-config-react-app@6.0.0
npm WARN node_modules/eslint-config-react-app
npm WARN   eslint-config-react-app@"^6.0.0" from gatsby@4.24.4
npm WARN   node_modules/gatsby
npm timing idealTree:node_modules/eslint-config-react-app Completed in 459232ms
...
```

I have tried to force the installation via `npm install --force`, which did not alter the result.
I have also tried to ignore peerDependencies through `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`, which also didn't work.

I wonder whether this is a dependency issue or somehow my GitLab runners are unable to install `npm` at a faster pace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being a connectivity issue from the corporate network on which I was running GitLab. Once fixed, the pipeline runs the job successfully.